# Acumatica Calculate Unbound Field

Tags: c#, erp, acumatica

i some problems about calculate **unbound** field, i want get value from **grid** by row index like **RowIndex** property in c#, is it available from acumatica?

```
protected virtual void BSMTActivityTypePlanDetail_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Row == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        BSMTActivityTypePlan head = new BSMTActivityTypePlan();
        BSMTActivityTypePlanDetail detail = (BSMTActivityTypePlanDetail)e.Row;

        for (int x = 0; x <= DetailActTypePlans.Select().RowCount; x++)
        {
            head.TotalPlanAct += DetailActTypePlans.
        }


    }
```

What could be the correct way to solve this problem? thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to ask? Could you rephrase your question?

Comment: Hmmm, since the RowSelected event always runs after the event chain execution, for example: RowUpdated -> ... (I can't remember exactly what run after RowUpdated) -> RowSelected, FieldUpdated -> ..... -> RowSelected so it could be heavy load or wrong calculation when you put in the RowSelected event. If your unbound field is only calculated at the first time the row is loaded then I suggest using the RowSelecting to do this calculation

Comment: @HDanh : thanks for your suggest, can i get value with row index property ?

Comment: Not sure what your end goal is but if you are looking to add child data up to a parent record or calculate an unbound field then you should look into PXFormula or PXUnboundFormula. Source the Acumatica source for examples of its use.

Comment: Formula attribute should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finnaly i'm using **PXDBScalar** and it's works on unbound field.

Answer (score 3):

I see 2 possible ways of arriving at a possible solution:

The first one is closer to what you would have liked to achieve: to use “foreach” instead of “for”:

```
foreach (DetailType detail in DetailView.Select())
{
    head.TotalPlanAct += detail.PlanActValue;
}
```

The other one would be to use a `view` with an aggregate, so that it would directly return you the total value and you won’t have to loop in your code to calculate it.

Comment: Thanks for your suggest